# Any C++ data mining library which also have the support of mysql?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, data-mining

Does any one know any good C++/C library for data mining which can be integrated with mysql.Basically I want something using which I can apply clustering , classification or association rules on a mysql DB.

Does any of these library also have the mysql support?I have a very large data set of around 1 million record which I can access through a good database only(instead of bringing them on any file or excel).I can also look for options which may not have the C++ support but are comprehensive and have good features.

Comment: data mining is a very ill-defined concept. Please define more what you want.

Comment: 1 millon rows is not that much... It depends of how many variables you are using. MAybe you can try R thats more statistics oriented i believe and easier to use. It will be better than excel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this source to find a suitable ML C++ library:

- [mloss.org filtered by C++](http://mloss.org/software/language/c__/)

Some recommended ML libraries for C++ :

- [Shark](http://shark-project.sourceforge.net/)
- [Shogun](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/)
- [libSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/)
- [DLIB](http://dlib.net/)
- [Waffles](http://waffles.sourceforge.net/docs.html)
- [LIBLINEAR](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/)
- [GibbsLDA++](http://gibbslda.sourceforge.net/)

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915341/which-machine-learning-library-to-use).